# Baire Category Theorem proof confusion

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

I am not understanding the following proof from Folland.

> **5.9 The Baire Category Theorem.** Let $X$ be a complete metric space.
>
> a. If $\left\{U_{n}\right\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of open dense subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} U_{n}$ is dense in $X$.
>
> b. $X$ is not a countable union of nowhere dense sets.
>
> Proof. For part (a), we must show that if $W$ is a nonemply open set in $X$, then $W$ intersects $\bigcap_{1}^{\infty} U_{n}$. Since $U_{1} \cap W$ is open and nonempty, it contains a ball $B\left(r_{0}, x_{0}\right)$, and we can assume that $0<r_{0}<1$. For $n>0$, we choose $x_{n} \in X$ and $r_{n} \in(0, \infty)$ inductively as follows: Having chosen $x_{j}$ and $r_{j}$ for $j<n$, we observe that $U_{n} \cap B\left(r_{n-1}, x_{n-1}\right)$ is open and nonempty, so we can choose $x_{n}, r_{n}$ so that $0<r_{n}<2^{-n}$ and $\overline{B\left(r_{n}, x_{n}\right)} \subset U_{n} \cap B\left(r_{n-1}, x_{n-1}\right)$. Then if $n, m \geq N$, we see that $x_{n}, x_{m} \in B\left(r_{N}, x_{N}\right)$, and since $r_{n} \rightarrow 0$, the sequence $\left\{x_{n}\right\}$ is Cauchy. As $X$ is complete, $x=\lim x_{n}$ exists. Since $x_{n} \in B\left(r_{N}, x_{N}\right)$ for $n \geq N$ we have
> $$
> x \in \overline{B\left(r_{N}, x_{N}\right)} \subset U_{N} \cap B\left(r_{0}, x_{0}\right) \subset U_{N} \cap W
> $$$x \in \overline{B\left(r_{N}, x_{N}\right)} \subset U_{N} \cap B\left(r_{0}, x_{0}\right) \subset U_{N} \cap W$
> for all $N$, and the proof is complete.
> As for (b), if $\left\{E_{n}\right\}$ is a sequence of nowhere dense sets in $X$, then $\left\{\left(\bar{E}_{n}\right)^{c}\right\}$ is a sequence of open dense sets. Since $\bigcap\left(\bar{E}_{n}\right)^{c} \neq \varnothing$, we have $\bigcup E_{n} \subset \bigcup \bar{E}_{n} \neq X$.

Why does showing an arbitrary open set intersect $U_N$ is not empty imply $\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty U_n$ is dense in $X$? Can this be phrased in terms of $\overline{\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty U_n}=X$?

Comment: What’s your definition of dense?

Comment: It is shown that $x \in U_{N} \cap W$ for all $N$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm sorry I'm not too advanced at topology as this is an analysis course. Why does this show density?

Comment: @Randall $A$ is dense in $X$ if $\overline{A}=X$

Comment: Phrase the closure being $X$ in terms of open sets and that does it.

Comment: @Randall Would it be the set union its accumulation points? I'm not sure how to represetn the closure in terms of open sets

Comment: $A$ being dense in $X$ means that every nonempty open set in $X$ contains a point of $A$.

Comment: @Randall I see now thank you!

Comment: One can imagine that in its embryonic historical beginnings, it was proved in a relatively non-abstract setting (e.g. the real line, or maybe a bit more generally in ${\mathbb R}^n)$ that the intersection of countably many dense open sets is not empty, after which it was observed that simply by doing everything within an arbitrarily specified open set $W$ at the beginning gets you even more than "is not empty", namely "is dense".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D$ is dense in $X$ iff $\overline{D} = X$. This is the standard definition.

This is equivalent to

> for all non-empty open sets $O$: $O \cap D\neq \emptyset$.

For if $O$ is non-empty and $O \cap D = \emptyset$ we have that $D \subseteq X\setminus O$, which is closed so $\overline{D} \subseteq X\setminus O \neq X$ and $D$ would not have $X$ as its closure. For the converse: let $C$ be a closed set that contains $D$. If $C\neq X$ then $X\setminus C$ would be non-empty open and disjoint from $D$, contradiction. So $X$ is the only closed superset of $D$ or $\overline{D}=X$.

This is applied in the proof to $D=\bigcap_n U_n$ and $O=W$. So we need to find a point in $W$ that lies in all $U_n$ and we're done.